# Error in icingaweb2 setup (openSUSE, nginx)

Tags: icinga

I have been trying to setup icinga2/icingaweb2 in our office following exclusively the official documentation. The base system is openSUSE (Leap 42.1) and the webserver is nginx.

Everything works smoothly and I can install all elements without problem after fixing one error: in packages.icinga.org/openSUSE/ICINGA-release.repo $releasever searches for "Leap 42" and there is no such folder, so I replaced that with a static "13.2" which is currently the latest release for openSUSE. For the installation of icinga2 I followed the documentation and everything worked out without errors.

To install icingaweb2 I follow [this official](https://github.com/Icinga/icingaweb2/blob/master/doc/02-Installation.md) document. The problem appears when I get to the point ["Preparing Web Setup"](https://github.com/Icinga/icingaweb2/blob/master/doc/02-Installation.md#-preparing-web-setup) - it looks absolutely straight forward with no option for error even for the biggest noob.

As it states, I try to access .../icingaweb2/setup and receive Error 404. The icingaweb2.conf file is in the right place, nginx/php5 is up and running, all databases are in place... Everything looks correct.

Has anyone had this problem or a suggestion from where it might originate? I could submit additional data if requested. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the nginx error log say?

Comment: This: 
[error] 1699#1699: *1 open() "/srv/www/htdocs/icingaweb2/setup" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: x.x.x.x, server: localhost, request: "GET /icingaweb2/setup HTTP/1.1", host: "x.x.x.x"

Answer (score 0):

We primarily focus on the SLES releases for SuSE at the moment, so the OpenSuSE releases might not be up to date.

There is however a package maintained by the SuSE guys over on [OBS](https://build.opensuse.org/package/show/server:monitoring/icingaweb2).

The package seems to install `icingaweb2.conf` somewhere into the Apache's config.

Make sure that the file is there and Apache is reloaded (without errors).

Comment: I've used nginx instead of apache and generated the icingaweb2.conf for nginx. It's also in the appropriate place as per the documentation.

Comment: I see, since I can't see your nginx config, I can only guess your mistake: `/srv/www/htdocs/icingaweb2` - thats not the way the RPM is installed - that would be `/usr/share/icingaweb2`

Comment: In /etc/nginx/icingaweb2.conf the path is specified as /usr/share/icingaweb2. Do I have to specify this path in nginx.conf too?

Comment: You posted above: `[error] 1699#1699: *1 open() "/srv/www/htdocs/icingaweb2/setup" failed (2: No such file or directory)` That suggests the nginx config is not working or not loaded.

Comment: I was trying to figure out which line of nginx.conf would call on /etc/nginx/icingaweb2.conf and the only part I could see is "include conf.d/*.conf" but there's no conf.d folder. Unfortunately the documentation wasn't very specific on this. Could you suggest where should I look for an edit please? Otherwise nginx status is running, syntax of conf is okay.

Answer (score 0):

Found two errors:

1. The generated icingaweb2.conf wasn't being loaded and I just copied its content into nginx.conf;
2. In php-fpm.conf I had missed a few points so it was not listening on any unix socket (listen = /var/run/php-fpm.sock)

Basically errors because of my very limited experience with nginx/php. Thanks for your suggestions and help!